# RE to NFA Thompson's construction steps ((c|a)b*)*

Tags: regex, algorithm, nfa

I tried to convert ((c|a)b*)* to an nfa by using thompsom's construction but I have understood something wrong because the outcome isn't the one it is supposed to be. I would be really glad if you could point my mistake.
Thompson's construction rules:

- 1)Every NFA has a start state and an accepting state.
- 2)No transition, except the starting one, is allowed to enter the start state.
- 3)No transition exits from an accepting state.
- 4)An ε-transition always connects 2 states that used to be start or accepting states for some REs
- 5)A state can have at maximum 2 incoming and 2 exiting ε-transitions
- 6)A state can at maximum 1 incoming and 1 exiting transition for a specific character of the alphanumerics used.

  **Step 1**: I created NFAs for each character

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 2**: parenthesis have priority so I created c|a
[image]

**Step 3**: then I created b*

[image]

**Step 4**: then I combined c|a and b* to create (c|a)b*

[image]

**Step 5**: and at last I created ((c|a)b*)*
[image]

The difference from the correct solution is that in the last nfa (the example doesn't show the steps and the states got renumbered in the end) there is no s9. So S8 ε-transists to S5 and S5 ε-transists to S10. Which makes sense to me if b* didn't have the S9 state but it needs it because of rule number 2. So I guess I made a mistake during the connection. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with your solution. The things you point out as differences are just common sense elisions (two epsilon transitions can be combined, e.g.).

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com, since there's no computer program anywhere in the question.

Comment: Ami tavory i get it but i have exams in some days and i want it to be perfect...

Comment: Doesn't rule 2 say that nothing can enter S11? I don't see how that's releveant.

Comment: I mentioned rule 2 for the creation of b*. I didn't know that i should combine states when concatenating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule 2 says that nothing can enter S11, which isn't relevant here. When concatenating (step 4), S8 and S9 should have been combined.

From Wikipedia,

> The concatenation expression *st* is converted to
>
> [image: Concatenation]